# Can i use both bootstrap 3 and bootstrap 4 in same html file for different-different divs in a webpage .if yes how to do this

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>bootstrap3 &bootstrap4 in same html file</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bootstrap3">
       some code here which require bootstrap3 css files
    </div>
    <div class="bootstrap4">
       some code here which requires bootstrap4 css files
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

i have problem in this section so please help me out to solve this

Comment: can you create an example why you need both...?

Comment: i m doing a project with a team.i made a html page using bootstrap 3 and others are using bootstrap 4.i hv to use their header.and if i add their bootstrap4 header stick to top and change color feature is not working....please help me out here

Comment: not a good practice, but if its possible try to import only header css not whole framework...

Comment: instead of trying this STRANGE and useless thing, read the boostrap 4 documentation to understand how it works in order to be able to create the same header as you did in the V3

Comment: `i m doing a project with a team.i made a html page using bootstrap 3 and others are using bootstrap 4` --> are you sure it's a team ? because a team is supposed to discuss and share before coding

Comment: Or, instead of putting effort in getting this short term solution, do it right and update to BS4?

Comment: Please try to upgrade to bootstrap 4 (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/) or get them to downgrade to bootstrap 3, using both in a project will get very messy.

Answer (score 11):

I believe the quick answer is No, for a number of reasons.

Note, While I believe you're talking about CSS, you don't exactly state whether you're talking about the CSS of bootstrap or the JS of bootstrap, or both.

Regardless, surely both bootstrap 3 and 4 both have styles and JS functions with the same names, and would surely conflict - or just be overwritten.  (The last thing loaded usually overwrites the previous thing loaded).

Secondly, a little comment here about cooperation.
The team should standardize on what to use, not go in different directions on something like this.  ("Too many chefs in the kitchen" comes to mind.)
There should be a serious talk / debate (not argument ) about the pluses and minuses of which bootstrap to use.  I acknowledge, that there are perfectly valid reasons not to use Bootstrap 4 (that's another story), but honestly - just because something is the latest thing, doesn't mean you HAVE to use it, and there are many more examples and "best practices" of Bootstrap 3 out there, at this point in time.
Regardless,I'd suggest that your team stay focused on solving the current problem at hand, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to integrate both bootstrap3 and bootstrap 4 because of many classes of the bootstrap library with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to stick to particular bootstrap and use it Throughout your project. As the functionality of every bootstrap differs from one another, it is not a good practice to use different bootstraps for 1 project.

So I would suggest you to use Bootstrap based on your project needs like for e.g: whether you want to build mobile-responsive site first or web-responsive, come to conclusion and then decide which Bootstrap suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can only if you duplicate any one css version and rename class so both version con't conflict. But this is not something feasible to do.