# Bootstrap 3.3 and 5.2 together without conflicts

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a site built using twitter bootstrap 3.3 in 2015+ and I want to incorporate newer features from bootstrap 5.2. Is there a way to include bootstrap 5.2 keeping the bootstrap 3.3 code ? Refactoring the entire code base to use bootstrap 5.2 would be a lot of work which would result in a "no" from management.

I see that using [3 and 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363846/can-i-use-both-bootstrap-3-and-bootstrap-4-in-same-html-file-for-different-diffe) together is a no-no - but what about 3 and 5.2 ?

Comment: My team when down this same design path with an old Bootstrap site we manage. The idea was to do an in-place migration over time. Yet, after some testing we abandon the idea.  There are too many conflicts and you end up writing code and markup that is very difficult to maintain.  Ultimately, it's faster, cleaner, and cheaper to migrate the entire site at one time.

Comment: Your pitch wasn't good enough. Make it very clear how painful it will be to keep an old library that has reached [end of life](https://github.com/twbs/release) and lacks modern layout features and accessibility. I've done it myself. The entire site migration took less than a day.

Comment: To answer your final question--Bootstrap 4 and 5 are quite similar. You won't have an easier time with 5 than you would have with 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining Bootstrap 3.3 and Bootstrap 5.2 together without conflicts can be challenging since both versions have different class names, structures, and features. However, it is possible to integrate them into the same project with some extra effort. Here's a general approach you can follow:

1. Avoid conflicting CSS and JS files: Make sure you don't include conflicting CSS and JS files from both versions. Include only the necessary files from each version to prevent conflicts. This may require renaming some classes or modifying the source code.
2. Namespace Bootstrap 3.3: Rename the classes and IDs used by Bootstrap 3.3 to avoid conflicts with Bootstrap 5.2. For example, you can prefix all Bootstrap 3.3 classes with a specific namespace, such as `.bs3-`, to differentiate them from Bootstrap 5.2 classes.
3. Load CSS and JS files in the correct order: Make sure to load the CSS and JS files in the correct order to ensure proper functionality. Load Bootstrap 3.3 files before Bootstrap 5.2 files to give priority to the older version.
4. Update class names and HTML structure: If you have existing HTML code that uses Bootstrap 3.3 classes, update the class names and HTML structure to match the changes introduced in Bootstrap 5.2. This might involve modifying your HTML code, replacing classes, and adjusting styles.
5. Test and debug: After integrating both versions, thoroughly test your website/application to identify any conflicts, layout issues, or unexpected behavior. Use your browser's developer tools to inspect elements, check for console errors, and address any conflicts or issues that arise.

Keep in mind that merging Bootstrap versions is not recommended, as it can lead to maintenance difficulties and inconsistencies in the design. It is generally better to migrate your project fully to Bootstrap 5.2 if possible, as it offers numerous improvements and features compared to Bootstrap 3.3.